# Why am I only able to read the first couple bytes of this file?

Tags: file-io, applescript

Internetizens, this little program returns the first two characters out of the file I specified.
This is surprising to me, as the source file contains a few hundred lines of text.
What am I doing wrong? Can someone wiser spot my error please?  Thank you!  :-D

```
-- This script will import to-dos and notes into Things from a plaintext file.
-- To run the script, click the green "Run" button in the toolbar above.
-- source:  https://culturedcode.com/things/support/articles/2803555/#import-from-a-plain-text-file
set unixPath to "/Volumes/2_TB_SSD_external/Projects_2TB/computers-and-geekery/projects and languages/Obsidian development/wealthyvault/bin/logs/things-commit.db"
-- set text_file to (open for access (POSIX file unixPath))

set text item delimiters to tab
set database_text to (read POSIX file unixPath as «class utf8»)
set numparagraphs to (count paragraphs of database_text)
return database_text
```

Comment: Works for me.  Will the script read some other text file?

Comment: Can you post the code you used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by changing `<<utf8>>` to `string`:

```
set database_text to (read POSIX file unixPath as «class utf8»)
```

became

```
set database_text to (read POSIX file unixPath as string)
```

I have no idea why, but this fixed the issue.